# how to prevent a part of a function inside website from running using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm working on a project to fill out a form automatically using selenuim python. it works pretty but when i click on send button, website clear the form content automatically by itself. The website uses a function named clearSendform() inside the JS codes to clear form. is there any way to prevent ClearSendForm() from running in submissionCalback()?

```
function submissionCalback(send) {
            if (send.IsSuccessfull) {
                if (!window.GlobalVar.myweb_settings.keepFieldsAfterSubmit ||
                    name1.nameid > 0 ||
                    pass1.passid > 0)
                    ClearSendForm();
                    var errorCode = send.MessageCode; 
                    Notify({ type: "error", text: translate(errorCode) });
        }
```

@florent-b
@andersson

Comment: Can you explain better both fixing the title and maybe adding some example code?

Comment: @axel
The question was edited

Comment: You can try filling up the form using [`JavascriptExecutor`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)

Comment: @user1207289 Does using javascriptExecutor prevent ClearSendForm() from running? can u explain how it does?